# Subsetting a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Probably an easy one.

I have a `data.frame` with three columns: `cluster`, `group`and `id`. Each

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster=letters[sample(length(letters),1000,replace=T)],
                 group=LETTERS[1:2][sample(2,1000,replace=T)],
                 id=1:1000)
```

Each `cluster` can be represented by either one or more `group`s, where each group can be represented by one or more `id`s.

I'm looking for a fast way to subset `df` retaining only rows whose `cluster`s have both `group`s are represented.

This is pretty slow for my real data dimensions:

```
library(dplyr)

do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l){
  if(length(unique(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)$group) == 2)){
    return(dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l))
  } else{
    return(NULL)
  }
})
```

Is there a faster way to do this with `dplyr`?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(cluster) %>% filter(n_distinct(group) > 1)`? Your sample data doesn't actually have any rows that get filtered out, though.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.